# Display problem after installing Win 7 on Macbook Pro 15 (2011)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, display

After installing Win 7 on my macbook via BootCamp I get a black screen on booting my macbook. And the brightness is very low  on Win 7 I cannot see any thing on Windows. But On mac all thing is fine and I have no problem. How can I solve this problem.
I really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this question:[MacBook Pro 15" 2011 display problem at loading](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52230/23055)