# MacBook Pro 15" 2011 display problem at loading

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I have a problem with my display, at loading time I can't see Apple logo and when I press `option` bottom to change the booting device I can not see any thing except a dark screen and my Mac comes out all thing is fine and I have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to the **[PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)** which stores startup disk and monitor depth settings.

> ### Resetting PRAM and NVRAM
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
> 3. Turn on the computer.
> 4. Press
>      and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> keys. You must press this key
>      combination before the gray screen appears.
> 5. Hold the keys down until
>      the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second
>      time.
> 6. Release the keys.